# Equivalent matlab damp function for Python

Tags: python, matlab

Does anybody know which is the equivalent (or any equivalent) matlab [damp](http://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/damp.html) function for Python (in scipy, numpy or some other)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I haven't personally used it, a quick google suggests that the [python control systems library](http://python-control.readthedocs.org/) might be what you're after.

It appears to implement the functionality of the MATLAB control systems toolbox with a compatibility mode which matches the same interface as in MATLAB.

Specifically the function you have asked for is [here](http://python-control.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/control.matlab.damp.html#control.matlab.damp).

Comment: Thank you so much @SimonGibbons ! I got lost looking for exactly this, and I haven't realized about this library you mention! This will help!